# How do you validate properties on an `unknown` typed parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm sure there is something super basic here but I can't quite figure it out. This is my first time digging into the `unknown` type and I'm using it to validate a user configuration file.

I'm aware that you have to basically check values on that unknown type to get typescript to get more and more information about the objects themselves. Here's what I have so far

```js
function validateJsonOverride(override: unknown) {
  if (typeof override !== "object") {
    throw new Error("Property `overrides` must be an array of objects");
  }
  if (override == null) {
    throw new Error("Elements in `overrides` cannot be null or undefined");
  }
  
  if (!("a" in override)) {
    throw new Error("Property `a` is required for json overrides");
  }
  if (!("b" in override)) {
    throw new Error("Property `b` is required for json overrides");
  }
  const {a, b} = override;
  return {
    a,
    b,
  };
```

However right now at the line `const {a, b} = override;` I get an error `Property 'a' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)`.

How are you supposed to clarify the types to typescript so that `a` and `b` do exist.

I also copied this into the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBNVQKYBSAzggPLJ4BOl2eAFHBdbQFyLgDWYcA7mAJSIA3gChEiGMER0oATwAOeOFMZUaWPIgCEAXh2IARHABGAKzzQDg0ePFQAFpV6IweHogCi1OJToGACk6KlHKIAAaqzBpEYYgAtiBEUIjGmqhIqNSosojKuWYWUERWANxiiAC+5ZLSkeqaei4g6OjW5XaOzq7uXk6+Bh7oeHF4YEUSSBFM9TGIEOncyalNLbmU7GAawDCuWKXlVeLVUnRafqgGE7nTtPxttogOTu7dnt79gXDBoWGSsTBERCUPAARxAMGBWEQwB8iFMJCQdVoxX4ZXEhwkJzOBmMlx21zUt3utieXTcbz6fk+3xyYQco3+gOBYIheChMPW8IQBKieBRaMq5QgCCSwlQABoUhVEPokRoBcCoCBKEgbA9EBL2rZjAcRBUgA) for easier replaying

Comment: `override as { a: <something>, b: <something> }`?

Comment: Sure, but in that case I might as well just use `any`. My goal here is to understand how to use property checks on the object to have typescript build a better picture of the object; not force cast to just get my code working.

Comment: Create a custom type guard. Btw, there is `Array.isArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is no longer an issue in typescript@>5. You're able to write the following code without needing `Record`, `is`, `as` or any custom typescript utility types - [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvAUFfUAhgFxTzABOAlgHYDmA3HgQEak2IC2LEFTAvjhwAzRDQDGwKgHsaUAG6FkVACaFgEAFLxZAeXm9qKiAAppBikYikxAaxrSA7jQCUpOElTZm+KsKgmoJDS-uaGqtAAhOiYAETSLABWEJKxLt4EmVDAABYUTlA0EI5QAKKW0hQmsQAK+ZAUoFAABmGWEfDNUJyI5FA8RHKEloQgUCHjSSnA8GlMmYKZfgFtVhiYHMjI6bhZBLn5JUUl5flVsaXIEJwQNDNQtC2rHV3ihDQOaAObyOMUUGJjMJaBAVHMfFBBBDliZItVCLEHnJnsYXDsIZkDgVjmUKuc6tIGk1moQulR4FAKBAAI6IKhUlRQYSVKCJHTIixWWYueYERYEGFw2IsRGPFEQNEZPbZPLY4q4s7VAlEsbNFhkilU2n00FMlls2TjTkdcELCHiWR9LBEAA0-UhGCN4WMvN8-kC4AgE0IUGicXI1HoaSleyxR3lp0qSvqvGJpLIOWkKEZAx9AdodFNfOh7qCXv8LF9MSgsQ43F4wd20rDhQjeOjhNjqvVCaTyBT0B9ZZ4FCz+ChmSpwEQFDkVb2hBtGNYU4WAiAA):

```
type Result = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

function validateJsonOverride(override: unknown): Result {
    if (typeof override !== "object") {
        throw new Error("Property `overrides` must be an array of objects");
    }
    if (override == null) {
        throw new Error("Elements in `overrides` cannot be null or undefined");
    }

    if (!("a" in override)) {
        throw new Error("Property `a` is required for json overrides");
    }
    if (!("b" in override)) {
        throw new Error("Property `b` is required for json overrides");
    }
    const { a, b } = override;
    if (typeof a !== "string") {
        throw new Error("Property `a` should be a string");
    }
    if (typeof b !== "number") {
        throw new Error("Property `b` should be a number");
    }

    return {
        a,
        b,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The absolutely type-safe way of doing it is

```
interface Something {
    a: string
    b: string
}
function overrideIsSomething(override: unknown): override is Something {
    function isSomethingLike(given: unknown): given is Partial<Record<keyof Something, unknown>> {
        return typeof given === 'object' && given !== null;
    }
    
    return isSomethingLike(override) && typeof override.a === 'string' && typeof override.b === 'string'
}
```

So you first assert it has a necessary shape then check its properties types.

Comment: Yep, this is the closest I've been able to get/find myself without using an `any` or an `as`. Nice!

Comment: I really don't see the value of adding all these complex codes just to make unknow work.

Comment: @Qiulang type safety does not come for free. If you have more concise/readable solution that is as safe as this one - I'd be keen to see it.

Comment: @zerkms no I don't have. Just seeing your codes makes me hesitate to use unknown

Comment: @Qiulang if you can come with solution that provides better readability, at least the same type safety and does not use `unknown` - then it's great ;-)

Comment: Actually, I found your answer because I hit a problem when using the updated version of `fast-xml-parse`,  please take a look if you are interested,  https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/issues/612

Answer (score 0):

In your case, a [User-Defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) would work:

```js
interface Something {
    a: string
    b: string
}

function overrideIsSomething(override: any): override is Something {
    return typeof override.a === 'string' && typeof override.b === 'string'
}
```

You can use `overrideIsSomething` like this:

```js
if (overrideIsSomething(override)) {
    // override is Something in this context
    const {a, b} = override;
    return {
        a,
        b,
    };
  }
```

**EDITED**

Leverage optional chaining for runtime safe in this specific case:

```js
function overrideIsSomething(override: any): override is Something {
    return typeof override?.a === 'string' && typeof override?.b === 'string'
}
```

It's simpler and works, but if you want the most type safe way, check zerkms's answer.

Comment: Your type guard is not type safe. Using `unknown` makes a little bit harder to make a mistake.

Comment: Actually type guard is type safe, what type guard do is refine parameter's type. You can still keep `if/else` branch code in `validateJsonOverride` or type guard.

Comment: "Actually type guard is type safe" --- if implemented correct. Your code will blow in runtime if you pass `null` there. If you used `unknown` not `any` you wouldn't have made that mistake.

Comment: That's true, and that's also apply to all most all of TypeScript types, cause types are omitted in runtime code. However, you can restrict type more strictly if you have more information: `function overrideIsSomething(override: SomethingA | SomethingB): override is SomethingA`. And you can also use something like [Optional chaining](overrideIsSomething(override: any)) to prevent runtime error.

Comment: "that's also apply to all most all of TypeScript types, cause types are omitted in runtime" --- I'm not sure what that means: TS provides you a way to implement type safe code. `any` breaks it. `unknown` - does not. TS code is not safe only if you deliberately choose to do so: eg using `any` or type casts. Your case is easily fixable: use `unknown` not `any`. `any` has very little _justified_ use (totally not this case).

Comment: `const data: Person = getFromNetwork(url); console.log(data.name)` this code is type safe in design time, but not safe in runtime. But yes, change `overrideIsSomething(override: any)` to `overrideIsSomething(override: unknown)` is safer in design time, it forces us to do some judgement. In this specific case, `any` and optional chaining may make the code look simpler.

Comment: This gave me an idea of instead of casting to any when I pull out the values (to work around the issue) to cast it via `  const {a, b} = override as { [key: string]: unknown };`. That said, I still am very curious how to get the unknown type to work correctly in this situation.

Comment: @k2snowman69 `as` cast is also not generally type safe. How to make unknown work here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EwAtQDmyA3gFDIXJwBcyAzmFIeZQEa0NMgGkC+pMAK4gEYYOhDJ0AN2hMAJhACSdDNjyEAFDLnBFtYQGsQ6AO4gAlLR1QFKYHTRYc+biRYUhIsROQO1LoQAMsCGEJoEwLIgBiDGZpa0kdF+jgAKcFBicAA2ADwAShAI6FDyeWEAnugwTuquBAA0yEYm5gB87e6UPchQOIJQkmCVAA4QNcjJEJIAvPPIAETorABWxWCLyABk21NRM8gAhAsggjk5ANweyPw9N-1gg5L+zhrcIWHasrZ6EBY7PYjcaTGx2AB0cGQ81myAA5JxCHDAchgRNamC-uDWNCFgjGEi+EA This code is type safe and makes no assumptions whatsoever.

Comment: @L_K "this code is type safe in design time, but not safe in runtime" --- it depends on how you implement it. All my code is type safe regardless where data comes from - from external URL request or anywhere else.

Comment: Why use interface?  Just make input a and b string with b optional?